# Do finite unions preserve cardinality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Please forgive me if this is a very basic question. I have never studied cardinals, I just need this result for a problem in Linear Algebra.

My question is: if $V_1, V_2, ..., V_n$ are infinite sets of the same cardinality, does $V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \cdots \cup V_n$ still have that same cardinality?

I can imagine a proof if the sets are countable: we can list the $V_i's$ in $n$ rows, and construct a "snake". However, I don't see how to generalize this to uncountable sets.

Comment: How much do you know about ordinals? The snake thing works if one "counts" not with elements of $\Bbb N$, but with suitable ordinals

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, I pretty much know zero about ordinals. I don't even know the definition of a cardinal or an ordinal, though I guess I could look those up. I am only familiar with the language of bijection/injection/surjection.